# Why is Core Animation available even without QuartzCore?

Tags: ios, core-animation, quartz-core

If the CALayer header is part of QuartzCore, I need to link against QuartzCore right? Right now my project links against UIKit, CoreGraphics, and Foundation. So then when I use CALayer in a header file, printed below in full… it compiles!

```
//
//  EGLSomeClass.h
//  SomeApp
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface EGLSomeClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) CALayer* aLayer;

@end
```

I guess if things are working when I thought they wouldn't that's a plus in a way, but I still want to know why I don't need QuartzCore to use Core Animation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look of this document so you can see how Core Animation stack technology is conformed.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: OK, so Core Animation functionality is available when importing UIKit or AppKit.